# What running quests and achievements are available on Fitocracy?

Tags: running, motivation, websites

I'm a beginner when it comes to running and I found [Fitocracy](http://fitocracy.com) to be a great way to motivate myself. I'm wondering - what Achievements and Quests are there available on the site to provide goals for a beginner?

So far I have:

- achievement: **I Seem To Be Lost** (Run 20 miles (32.2 km) in your lifetime)
- quest: **Go For A Jog...** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 12 minutes) +50 pts
- quest: **Someone's Chasing Me!** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 10 minutes) +100 pts
- quest: **They're Getting Closer...** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 9 minutes) +200 pts
- quest: **Starting To Pull Away!** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 8 minutes) +300 pts
- quest: **The Pack Is Behind You!** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 7 minutes) +400 pts
- quest: **Finally 5k** (Run 5 km (3.11 miles) in one session) +100 pts

I can also see two "follow-up" quests:

- quest: **Veteran Runner Right Here!** (Run 1 mile (1.61 km) in under 6 minutes) +600 pts
- quest: **Trying 10k** (Run 10 km (6.22 miles) in one session) +200 pts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this question really counts as fitness-related, but hey, here you go.

Fitocracy seems to have a pretty obvious programming flaw which allows you to see the names and descriptions of all quests even if you aren't supposed to see them.

Log into Fitocracy, then open another browser tab and request this URL:

http://www.fitocracy.com/get_quest/3/

If you replace "3" with other numbers, one after the other, you get the HTML snippet with the quest, and it doesn't check whether you have access. So that way you can see all quests in the system. If you're really passionate you could write a robot which does this, parses the HTML and puts the info into a CSV or database or whatever. But there aren't that many quests anyway.

Achievements are all visible to anyone, apparently, so no point repeating them here.

I'm pretty sure the Fitocracy people will see this post, so I hope they'll see it as a favor to them and fix it.

*Source:* Competitive intelligence work for startup companies.

Comment: Just as a note, the provided method no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

After "veteran runner right here", comes "Mile record here I come!" ( Run  a mile in under 5 minutes)
After trying 10k comes "heroic half marathon" and then theres "MAster of MArathons"